# Shorthand class constructor member initialisation

Tags: java, syntax, constructor

Writing simple constructors in Java is pretty verbose. For each field that needs to be initialised you need to write the variable name four times, e.g. like so:

```
class X {
    int y;
    public X(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Is there a shorthand for that like e.g. in Kotlin?

This question was asked before here: [Shorthand class constructor field initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384061/shorthand-class-constructor-field-initialisation)

But that was way back in 2013 (6 Java versions ago) and the comments in this ([Ask for update to answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269631/ask-for-update-to-answers)) meta post say to post another question to request an answer for a newer version.

Also, the original question wasn't really answered since the answers focussed on chaining constructors instead. And according to the rules, a question that has not been answered cannot be the reason that another question is flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: No; Java is still verbose. One option would be to look at the current JLS--all Java syntax is readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Lombok makes Java much less verbose. Using it's annotations you can skip a lot of Java Boilerplate.

For constructors there are `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`.

Answer (score 1):

With Java <= 13 there is no way to make it less verbose.